# $A$ and $A+y$ are homeomorphic where $A$ is open set

Tags: general-topology

Actually I need to understand $A+B$ is open whenever $A,B$ open set in $\mathbb{R}$

First I want to prove $A$ and translation of $A$ by $y,y\in B$ are homeomorphic

$f:A\to A+y, f(x)=x+y$  may be the homeomorphism?

now $A+B=\cup_{y\in B}(A+y)$ is arbitrary union of open set will be open. is my proof correct?

Comment: Why did you make a tag for this..?

Comment: Also yes your proof is correct.

Comment: You only need $A$ to be open.

Comment: For your general problem, suppose $x \in A+B$. Then $x=y+z$ for $y \in A$ and $z \in B$. Now find an open neighborhood of $z$, call it $O$, which is contained in $B$. Then how can you find an open subset of $A+B$ using $O$?